# What is "alias attachment" used for in Vulkan?

Tags: graphics, rendering, vulkan

Vulkan has this flag: VK_ATTACHMENT_DESCRIPTION_MAY_ALIAS_BIT to make an attachment to share the same physical space with another attachment.
But when is this useful? after some search I found it seems no one is using it.

Answer (score 1):

Same reason you would use `union`. Aliased resources would use the same memory. That assumes though two aliases are never used at the same time, which limits usability.